# Website Vitals: Oops! Something went wrong

Tags: performance, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals, web-vitals

Hello I am testing my website and I have an score of about 80-90/100 if I look it with Chrome Lighthouse Extension. But in web.dev/measure and https://pagespeed.web.dev

The report returns an error. There is no error in console and there is no indication on what error is. I opened network inspector to see what web.dev was returning and this is what it said:

```
Lighthouse returned error: NO_FCP. The page did not paint any content. Please ensure you keep the browser window in the foreground during the load and try again. (NO_FCP)
```

But this is not true, the website loads fast, and works if I check it with the CLI or the Chrome Extension.

Any ideas on how can I debug this to find what is causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: Also try posting on the PageSpeed Insights forum: https://groups.google.com/g/pagespeed-insights-discuss

Comment: @RickViscomi Done, I guess is pending moderation